# Getting Media Query to work

Tags: magento2, less-css

Hi I'm adapting a Luma based theme. So I created the file _extend.less in

```
app/frontend/design/MyTemplate/theme_new/web/css/source/
```

> In that file I have:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m){
    .page-header {
        background:#f0bd70;
    } }
```

> And also tried:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .page-header {  border: 0;  margin-bottom: 0;   height: 120px;  background-color: #73C70F ; } }
```

> Both are not working?
>
> I also have included:

```
.page-header {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #73C70F ;
}
```

Which works fine.

So what am I doing wrong?

I use client side Compilation Module. I know css but are not familiar with less unfortunately. So how to get a media query to work in Magento2 Theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your following code in **_extend.less** working fine...

```
.page-header {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #73C70F ;
}
```

Then just make sure your code inside media query isn't override by some other media query (Check in inspect elements). Or try with `!important` for testing purpose.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .page-header {  
       border:1px solid red !important;
       background-color: #73C70F !important;
     }
}
```

If above code is working fine then surely other code is overriding your media query code for class `.page-header`

Comment: Hi tried the red border one with !important; Than I saw that I needed to have @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) having this applied to the smaller screen only. Also made sure that the query was below the .page-header css. Now its even working without the !important part added.